# How to close Window Switcher

Tags: autohotkey

On Windows 8.1.

I assigned "Run Window Switcher" to "^r".
And now I want to close the window switcher when I release "LControl" but I don't know how.
With the normal "alt+tab" hotkey, it is closed when you release the key "alt".

The below snippet for opening the window switcher works fine. I can also shift the current window by clicking the "r" key keeping the "LControl" key down. (I copied "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Window Switcher.lnk" to "C:\Users\myname\Documents\" by the way)

```
^r::Run, "C:\Users\myname\Documents\Window Switcher"
```

But the below snippet for closing the window switcher doesn't work.

```
LCtrl Up::Send,{Enter}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little *hackish*, but it still does the job fine:

```
^r::
    ; No need to rely on any shortcut here!
    Run, explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}
    KeyWait, Control
    if(WinActive("ahk_class TaskSwitcherWnd")) {
        Send, {Enter}
    }
return

#IfWinActive ahk_class TaskSwitcherWnd
^r::
    Run, explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}
return
```

The trick is to create two hotkeys: One that triggers if Window Switcher isn't already opened, and one that triggers if it is. The former "outer" hotkey will wait until <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is released and then close Window Switcher. The other "inner" hotkey registers every *switch* and delegates it.

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfect! I almost gave up. Thank you so much.